# Remove text in txt file between two markers in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making an application in Visual Basic 2010 that will allow me to easily create .dev web addresses for my XAMPP local hosted sites.

So far, I've managed to add to the necessary files, but not remove.

I need a way to remove all text between two markers in a txt file. For example:

```
120.0.0.1    localhost
120.0.0.1    alsolocalhost

##testsite.dev#start#
127.0.0.1    testsite.dev
##testsite.dev#stop#

##indevsite.dev#start#
127.0.0.1    indevsite.dev
##indevsite.dev#stop#
```

I want to remove all the text between the ##testsite.dev#start# and ##testsite.dev#stop# markers, as well as removing the markers themselves.

In my visual basic code this is what I have so far:

```
Sub removeText(ByVal siteName)
    Dim fileName As String = "hosts.txt"
    Dim startMark As String = "##" + siteName + "#start#"
    Dim stopMark As String = "##" + siteName + "#stop#"

    'Code for removing text...

End Sub
```

All I need now is to be able to remove the text I want, without touching any of the other text (this includes not messing with it's formatting).

Comment: Do you need to remove the complete line of both markers?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to remove both markers and everything between them.

Comment: You can not _remove_ anything from a textfile (though you might overwrite parts of it). The normal way is to read the file, process the content and then write a new file or overwrite the old one with the changed content.

Comment: @igrimpe Would it be possible to overwrite the selected text with nothing or a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read all, make a backup copy and then write line by line checking the current block status (inside/outside)

```
Sub removeText(ByVal siteName)
    Dim fileName As String = "hosts.txt"
    Dim startMark As String = "##" + siteName + "#start#"
    Dim stopMark As String = "##" + siteName + "#stop#"

    ' A backup first    
    Dim backup As String = fileName + ".bak"
    File.Copy(fileName, backup, True)

    ' Load lines from the source file in memory
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(backup)

    ' Now re-create the source file and start writing lines not inside a block
    Dim insideBlock as Boolean = False
    Using sw as StreamWriter = File.CreateText(fileName)
        For Each line As String in lines
            if line = startMark
               ' Stop writing
               insideBlock = true 

            else if line = stopMark
               ' restart writing at the next line
               insideBlock = false 

            else if insideBlock = false
               ' Write the current line outside the block
               sw.WriteLine(line) 
            End if
        Next         
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: wasn't exactly what I was looking for but this answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the file isnt huge, you could just read the whole thing to a string and remove like so:

```
    Dim siteName As String = "testsite.dev"
    Dim fileName As String = "hosts.txt"
    Dim startMark As String = "##" + siteName + "#start#"
    Dim stopMark As String = "##" + siteName + "#stop#"
    Dim allText As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)
    Dim textToRemove = Split(Split(allText, startMark)(1), stopMark)(0)
    textToRemove = startMark & textToRemove & stopMark

    Dim cleanedText = allText.Replace(textToRemove, "")

    IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, cleanedText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the *usual* way, you might accomplish your goal with something like this:

```
    Dim startmark, stopmark As String
    Dim exclude As Boolean = False

    Using f As New IO.StreamWriter("outputpath")
        For Each line In IO.File.ReadLines("inputpath")
            Select Case line
                Case startmark
                    exclude = True
                Case stopmark
                    exclude = False
                Case Else
                    If Not exclude Then f.WriteLine()
            End Select
        Next
    End Using
```

And when you are done, delete the "old" file and rename the new one.